# Package a WAR in with a JBoss SAR

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jboss

I have a JBoss SAR with which I'd like to package a WAR (A Spring MVC web app). The reason being for this web application to be available on any JBoss where this SAR is deployed. I've added a dependency on the WAR in the SAR's POM and see that they're packaged together in the SAR. However, the web app isn't found when I open its URL, whereas if I deploy the web app separately, it opens ok.

**Edit**
I'm now trying to package the WAR and SAR into an EAR. I verified that I can deploy the SAR and WAR separately and that they each work this way. I verified that the WAR deploys correctly when packaged in the EAR with the SAR. However, the SAR is not deployed when packaged in the EAR. Here is the EAR's POM (identifiers made generic):

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>my-ear</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<!-- name, url, properties omitted -->

<dependencies>
<!-- NOT Deploying -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>MySAR</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>sar</type>
</dependency>
<!-- Deploys OK -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyWAR</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <modules>
                    <sarModule>
                        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
                        <artifactId>MySAR</artifactId>
                    </sarModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
                        <artifactId>MyWAR</artifactId>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually do that. A service archive (SAR) is meant to define components that are loaded and function independently. The most obvious form is a service that you deploy on the JMX domain.

A sar can either be deployed independently or it can be bundled in an EAR (see [support in the maven ear plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html#sarModule)).

But you can't deploy a web application in a sar. You should have two different deployment units for those or package them in an EAR.

Comment: Thanks - I've added an edit. As an EAR, the WAR deploys, but the SAR doesn't. Is there anything wrong with the EAR's POM?

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need to add the modules in the plugin's configuration unless you want to tune the configuration. Those are detected automatically by the plugin. Your pom looks good otherwise, there's no reason it wouldn't work. Can you add some relevant JBoss logs?

Comment: I may need to post a new question, the WAR and SAR in the EAR both actually deploy fine now, so you've given the correct answer. Long story short, an entirely separate app (a WAR) calls the service that's provided by the SAR before the SAR has been deployed and throws an error. If I deploy the EAR first, then deploy the calling app, everything is fine. I don't want to rely on that manual intervention though as sometimes JBoss will simply be restarted. I don't suppose there's a way to control the deployment order?

Comment: sounds like this would require a separate question. Regarding what you called the correct answer, you may want [to check this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Next question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693884/war-deployment-to-jboss-fails-because-it-calls-a-sar-packaged-in-an-ear